Applying for remote EU position from the US. How to answer, "Are you eligible to work in the EU?"
I am a US citizen living in the US. I have been looking for a new remote based job and a lot of the jobs that interest me have been posted by countries in the EU. When I apply for the jobs, I frequently see the question "Are you eligible to work in the EU (or some specific country therein)?" and you can only ever answer "yes" or "no". I get tripped up on whether this question is asking about if I currently have a visa or if I would be eligible for a work visa at all.
If I am applying for a remote EU job from the US and I currently don't have any kind of visa, is the answer to this question "no"?
I've tried to do searches for this information but I can only ever find results talking about someone living in the EU and applying for a US job.

Websearch for "eligible to work in EU" finds multiple resources, including some specific to US citizens. What question do you have that those don't answer? Or are you hoping to be told there's a loophole?

That literal search does not yield that same answers for me. I don't know why.

You would know if you are eligible to work in the EU. If you haven’t received that eligibility then you don’t have permission to work in the EU.

That is very much what I suspected but didn't want to eliminate the possibility without at least looking into it.

Law-wise, you are not eligible to work in the EU unless you hold a residence permit of the country you are working in, are a family member of a EU/EEA citizen or hold the citizenship of a EU/EEA country

Simply due to regulatory compliance, 99% of EU companies advertising remote roles will be unable to hire someone in the US.  Those who are willing to do so will advertise a remote position in the US.
You're getting that question because they're not able to hire you if you can't live and work in the EU.
Depending on your ancestry you might have a right to live/work there.  Some EU countries will grant it to all the descendants of people who emigrated from there decades or centuries ago.

Thanks, this was what I suspected and didn't want to waste my time applying for these jobs if this was the case.
